# Why do I have objects rendering transparent after use Cell Fracture addon

Tags: rendering, objects, add-on, transparency, cell-fracture

Who can help with the problem? Blender 3.1 when I use the cell Fracture addon I want to make a destruction effect. After I play the scene - I go into render - the object becomes transparent, although the same object is not rendered transparent without using cell fracture addons.
When I go to any settings, and change and go to render, the object is not transparent, but as soon as the scene changes and after pressing play set, the object is again rendered transparent.  can’t understand what needs to be changed so that after using cell Fracture addons, the object, like the original, is rendered not transparent.

[image]

Comment: I just solved this problem. I turn off Motion Blure. I usually always enable this feature, but when using Cell-Fracture addons when rendering, you need to disable it and the object will be as it should be.

Comment: I suggest you add that as an answer for the benefit of anyone else searching for that problem. (You can add answers to your own question.) I've edited the title of your question slightly to make more sense.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "transparent" in this case. I cannot see the environment behind the object so it is not transparent. Or do you mean there are some Z-fighting artifacts (hard to tell with this very low image quality, maybe post a proper screenshot of the render or the rendered image itself)? Maybe it's because you still have the original unfractured object visible in place? //EDIT: seems like writing my comment took too long :D